# How to show task revisions in custom grid?

Tags: rally, appsdk2

I have a custom grid that displays open tasks filtered by (Owner = some-user@company.com).

I would like to include the last revision for each task in a custom grid, but the Revision column is not available on the settings dialog. How to traverse from Revision History to individual revisions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can't be done with a custom grid, but can be done with a custom code. Here is an app example that populates a grid based on a selection in the [UserSearchComboBox](https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc2/doc/#!/api/Rally.ui.combobox.UserSearchComboBox) , and then displays the last revision of a selected task on a click event.

You may copy the html file into a custom page from [this github repo](https://github.com/nmusaelian-rally/last-revision-of-task/blob/master/deploy/App.html):

Here is the js file:

```
Ext.define('CustomApp', {
    extend: 'Rally.app.App',
    componentCls: 'app',

        launch: function() {
        var context  = this.getContext (); 
        var currentProject = context.getProject()._ref;
        var panel = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
                layout: 'hbox',
                itemId: 'parentPanel',
                componentCls: 'panel',
                items: [
            {
                    xtype: 'rallyusersearchcombobox',
                    fieldLabel: 'SELECT USER:',
            project: currentProject,
                        listeners:{
                            ready: function(combobox){
                                this._onUserSelected(combobox.getRecord());
                           },
                           select: function(combobox){
                if (this.down('#c').html !== 'No task is selected') {
                Ext.getCmp('c').update('No task is selected');
                }
                                this._onUserSelected(combobox.getRecord());
                           },
                            scope: this
                        }
                    },
            {
                    xtype: 'panel',
                    title: 'Tasks',
            width: 600,
                    itemId: 'childPanel1'
            },
            {
                    xtype: 'panel',
                    title: 'Last Revision',
            width: 600,
                    itemId: 'childPanel2'
            }
                ],
            });


            this.add(panel);
        this.down('#childPanel2').add({
        id: 'c',
        padding: 10,
        maxWidth: 600,
        maxHeight: 400,
        overflowX: 'auto',
        overflowY: 'auto',
        html: 'No task is selected'
        });
        },

        _onUserSelected:function(record){
            var user = record.data['_ref'];
           if(user){
            var filter = Ext.create('Rally.data.QueryFilter', {
                                 property: 'Owner',
                                 operator: '=',
                                 value: user
                             });

                             filter = filter.and({
                                 property: 'State',
                                 operator: '<',
                                 value: 'Completed'  
                             });
                             filter.toString();

              Ext.create('Rally.data.WsapiDataStore', {
                 model: 'Task',
                 fetch: [ 'DragAndDropRank','FormattedID','Name','State','RevisionHistory'],
                 autoLoad: true,
                 filters : [filter],
                 sorters:[
                    {
                        property: 'DragAndDropRank',
                        direction: 'ASC'
                    }
                 ],

                 listeners: {
            load: this._onTaskDataLoaded,
            scope: this
                 }
             });
           }
        },

    _onTaskDataLoaded: function(store, data) {
        var customRecords = [];
        Ext.Array.each(data, function(task, index) {
        customRecords.push({
            _ref: task.get('_ref'),
            FormattedID: task.get('FormattedID'),
            Name: task.get('Name'),
            RevisionID: Rally.util.Ref.getOidFromRef(task.get('RevisionHistory')),
        });
        }, this);
       this._updateGrid(store,data);
    },

        _updateGrid: function(store, data){
        if (!this.down('#g')) {
        this._createGrid(store,data);
    }
    else{
        this.down('#g').reconfigure(store);
    }
   },
        _createGrid: function(store,data){
            var that = this;
        var g = Ext.create('Rally.ui.grid.Grid', {
            id: 'g',
            store: store,
            enableRanking: true,
            columnCfgs: [
                    {text: 'Formatted ID', dataIndex: 'FormattedID'},
                    {text: 'Name', dataIndex: 'Name'},
                    {text: 'State', dataIndex: 'State'},
                    {text: 'Last Revision',
                         renderer: function (v, m, r) {
                        var id = Ext.id();
                        Ext.defer(function () {
                            Ext.widget('button', {
                            renderTo: id,
                            text: 'see',
                            width: 50,
                            handler: function () {
                                console.log('r', r.data);
                                that._getRevisionHistory(data, r.data);
                            }
                            });
                        }, 50);
                        return Ext.String.format('<div id="{0}"></div>', id);
                        }

                    }
                    ],
            height: 400,
    });
    this.down('#childPanel1').add(g); 
   },

    _getRevisionHistory: function(taskList, task) {
    this._task = task;
                this._revisionModel = Rally.data.ModelFactory.getModel({
                    type: 'RevisionHistory',
                    scope: this,
            success: this._onModelCreated
        });

    },
    _onModelCreated: function(model) {
        model.load(Rally.util.Ref.getOidFromRef(this._task.RevisionHistory._ref),{
            scope: this,
            success: this._onModelLoaded
        });

    },

     _onModelLoaded: function(record, operation) {
        record.getCollection('Revisions').load({
            fetch: true,
            scope: this,
            callback: function(revisions, operation, success) {
                this._onRevisionsLoaded(revisions, record);
            }
        }); 
    },

    _onRevisionsLoaded: function(revisions, record) {
        var lastRev = _.first(revisions).data;
    console.log('_onRevisionsLoaded: ',lastRev.Description, lastRev.RevisionNumber, lastRev.CreationDate );
    this._displayLastRevision(lastRev.Description,lastRev.RevisionNumber, lastRev.CreationDate );

    },

    _displayLastRevision:function(desc, num, date){
    Ext.getCmp('c').update('<b>' + this._task.FormattedID + '</b><br/><b>Revision CreationDate: </b>' + date +'<br /><b>Description:</b>' + desc + '<br /><b>Revision Number:</b>' + num + '<br />');
    }
});
```

[image]